# How to get number value from array or string?

Tags: php, numbers

I have a list on the page. And I want to get only amount (to be more specific, only total sum). So I tryed ot do it via post an array which i transform and i get rows like:

```
"recived from player"

"0.000058"

"2014-06-30 15:21:46 UTC"
```

I have tryied to get an `if(is_numeric($row1))` but it doesn't work (blank page).

```
    foreach ($p as $r) {
    $row = str_replace("\t",'<br />',$r);
            $row1 = str_replace("silver","",$row);
        if (is_numeric($row1)) {
            echo $row1;
        }
}
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: can you put a print_r of $p please --> <pre> <?php print_r($p); ?> </pre>

Comment: <?php var_dump($_POST)  ?> and see what you get

Comment: floatval($row1) should do the trick, but I'm not understanding your variable names which is where I'm guessing your problem is

Comment: @Su4p print_r($p) output: Array ( [0] => received from libby 0.00000300 silver 2014-07-01 9:53:38 UTC received from leow 0.00000050 silver 2014-07-01 9:53:25 UTC )
1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better to split string to array and then check for Number.

```
      $wordChunks = explode(" ", $someWords);  

      for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++)
           {
                if (is_numeric($wordChunks[$i])) 
                      {
                        echo $wordChunks[$i];
                      }

           }
```

Comment: And this is a best! Thank you!